# PHPによるデータベースのupdate文が意図した通り反映されない

Tags: php, sql

現在、学生の登録システムを作成していますが、生徒情報をupdateする作業が上手くいきません。
以下のページを元にphpを作成していますが、現在名前だけは更新できるものの、他の情報の更新ができません。
https://noumenon-th.net/programming/2016/01/20/mysql-3/

生徒情報を表示したページから、編集をクリックすると編集画面になり、編集画面では、前ページから引っ張ってきた情報を予めValueに入れ、変更の為の入力があった場合は変更された文字をValueに入れてデータベースの情報を更新したいと考えています。

現在、試行錯誤している為、名前と性別のupdateのみとなっております。
update2sample.php の49行目に`$Gender`を記入し、`UPDATE studentinfo SET Name=?, Gender=? WHERE id=?` や `UPDATE studentinfo SET Name=:Name, Gender=:Gender WHERE id=?`なども試しましたが、うまくいきません。

また、テストの為、色々作業を試しているのですが、実際にはデータベースの更新がされていないにも関わらず、「更新が完了しました」と表示されてしまう為、エラー表記につきましてもご教授ください。

初めての質問の為、不明点などあるかと思いますが、お力添えのほどよろしくお願いいたします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

現在、名前は更新できるのですが、その他の内容が更新できません。
現在は、途中の為、名前と性別のupdateを試しています。

#### 該当のソースコード

**SELECT文にて下記表示**

```html
<div class="button">
<form action="update1sample.php" method="post">


<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($row['Name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>">
<input type="hidden" name="Gender" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($row['Gender'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')?>">
<input type="submit" value="編集">
</form>

</div>
```

**updatesample1.php**

```php
require_once("db_studentinfo.php");
$mysqli = db_connect();

if(empty($_POST)) {
    echo "<a href='update1.php'>update1.php</a>←こちらのページからどうぞ";
    exit();
}else{
    if (!isset($_POST['id'])  || !is_numeric($_POST['id']) ){
        echo "IDエラー";
        exit();
    }else{
        //プリペアドステートメント
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE id=?");
        if ($stmt) {
            //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id, $Name, $Gender);
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $Name = $_POST['Name'];
            $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];

            //クエリ実行
            $stmt->execute();

            //結果変数のバインド
            $stmt->bind_result($id,$Name,$Gender);
            // 値の取得
            $stmt->fetch();

            //ステートメント切断
            $stmt->close();
        }else{
            echo $mysqli->errno . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
}

<body>
<h1>変更画面</h1>

<p>変更箇所を入力してください</p>
<form action="update2sample.php" method="post">
<p>名前：<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($Name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>"></P>
<p>性別：<input type="text" name="Gender" placeholder="" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($Gender, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>"></P>


<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">
<input type="submit" value="変更する">
</form>

</body>
```

**updatesample2.php**

```php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

require_once("db_studentinfo.php");
$mysqli = db_connect();

if(empty($_POST)) {
    echo "<a href='update1.php'>update1.php</a>←こちらのページからどうぞ";
    exit();
}else{
    //名前入力チェック
    if (!isset($_POST['Name'])  || $_POST['Name'] === "" ){
        $errors['Name'] = "名前が入力されていません。";
    }

    if(count($errors) === 0){
        //プリペアドステートメント
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE studentinfo SET Name=? WHERE id=?");
        if ($stmt) {
            //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
            $stmt->bind_param('si', $Name, $id);
            $Name = $_POST['Name'];
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];



            //クエリ実行
            $stmt->execute();
            //ステートメント切断
            $stmt->close();
        }else{
            echo $mysqli->errno . $mysqli->error;
        }
    }
}
<h1>変更画面</h1>

<?php if (count($errors) === 0): ?>
<p>変更完了しました。</p>
<?php elseif(count($errors) > 0): ?>
<?php
foreach($errors as $value){
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/194628

Comment: MySQLの「studentinfo」 テーブルに「Gender」というフィールドは存在しますか？

Answer (score 0):

updatesample1.php

- SELECT文で取得した内容を表示しているので POST で $Name, $Gender を与える必要な無いと思います。

```php
   if ($stmt) {
        //プレースホルダへ実際の値を設定する
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        //$Name = $_POST['Name'];               <-この行は不要
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        //$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];           <-この行は不要
```

updatesample1.php

- UPDATE 文は `UPDATE studentinfo SET Name=?, Gender=? WHERE id=?` で大丈夫です。
- `bind_param()` で `$Name`, `$Gender`, `$id` を UPDATE文 のパラメータにバインドしてください。
- 最初の引数は バインド変数の型を表します。Genderの型が文字列であれば `ssi` です。

```php
        // SET句に Gender を追加
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE studentinfo SET Name=?, Gender=? WHERE id=?"); 
        if ($stmt) {
            // SQLパラメータに変数をバインド。? の出現順にそれぞれ次をバインドする
            //  1. 値：$Name    型:s(文字列)
            //  2. 値：$Gender  型:s(文字列)
            //  3. 値：$id      型:i(整数)
            $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $Name, $Gender, $id);
```

こんな感じではないでしょうか。

ご参考までに、マニュアルを見るなどして、SQLとbind_param() の関係を 一度整理してみると 理解が早くなるかと思います。https://www.php.net/manual/ja/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: take88様 ご回答ありがとうございます。早速試してみましたが、更新ができませんでした。 updatesample1.php: `//$Name = $_POST['Name']; //$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];` は、編集の前段階に、データベースからの情報をValueに入れるため、入れております。もしくは、予め `<p>性別：<input type="text" name="Gender" placeholder="" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($Gender, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>"></P>` と入れているため、編集前の情報がそのままデータベースに送られ、更新できないといったことも考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: updatesample1.php については 意図が分かっておりませんでした。回答からは撤回します。 「$Gender」には どんな値が入りますか？